# How do I soundproof the gap under an interior door over a hardwood floor?

Tags: doors, sound-proofing, weatherstripping, air-sealing

I have an interior door over a hardwood floor. The door lets in a lot of sound through the gap between the door and the floor. How do I soundproof the gap between the door and the floor?

[image: a door with a gap under it]

I tried adding a "draft stopper" strip [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MSM6G9R) last year. It helps significantly with the sound, but degrades a little over time, so I'm looking for a more robust solution. Is there some better version of "weatherstripping" I can use?

Adding to the complication, the door isn't hung at exactly 90 degrees, so the gap is slightly larger when the door is shut than when it's open. (Anything used to cover the gap needs to be flexible.) In my case, the gap is rather large - 1.5 in.

Comment: Be aware that if you have forced air heating/cooling and the room only has a supply vent, the gap under the door is the return vent (from the room to wherever the actual return air duct opening is) when the door is closed.

Comment: Great tip! In my case, the door goes to a room that does have a return vent, but that's important to know for anyone else who looks at this!

Comment: How about something simple like a stuffed draught stopper.

Comment: A rug with a really high pile. Even if it doesn't fill the gap, it'll help with the sound. Also, more rugs elsewhere. Outside is a hallway? whole thing needs a floor runner. And a good size one in the middle of that room too.

Comment: Closing the gap is worth trying, but some frequencies of sound may couple through walls and doors surprisingly well unless they are designed to prevent it. See other answers about soundproofing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I soundproof a bathroom door?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9040/how-can-i-soundproof-a-bathroom-door)

Comment: @RohitGupta agreed.  OP could get the type of draft stopper that's basically a fabric tube filled with sand (or legumes) and screw it to the lower part of the door.  The door would be harder to open and close, obviously, but sound would be reduced—at least from the bottom.  Sound could still propagate through the jambs and top of the door.

Comment: Brush strip wouldn't degrade as fast

Comment: You could add a threshold under the position of the closed door to make the closed gap the same or even smaller than the open gap.

Comment: Are there any thresholds that would be easy to install over an interior wood floor like this?

Answer (score 16):

If you really want to go for it, make sure you have a solid core door and install an automatic drop down door seal.

An example (no endorsement — I’d try to find something from Pemco):
[https://www.amazon.com/Automatic-Bottom-Fully-Mortised-Neoprene/dp/B00MEHON4G](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MEHON4G)

Comment: This is what we use for soundproofing doors for music practice rooms in schools, privacy in medical and legal consultation rooms, and the like.  The seal rises readily when the door is open to pass readily over carpet, will accommodate the gap angle, and are very effective and long-lived.  We also seal the other three door frame edges with dense compressible foam rubber.  (This is based on my experience as an audiovisual consultant specializing in acoustics for learning environments.)

Comment: Curious why you say the door must be solid core?

Comment: @MadMonty, the installation process involves cutting a groove in the bottom of the door.  Non-solid doors get most of their structural strength from the surface, so cutting a groove will compromise that strength.

Comment: @MadMonty Besides, solid-core doors are much more effective as a sound barrier than hollow core doors. Installing this on a hollow door is not the best combination.

Comment: @MadMonty — what they said ^^. The hollow core door probably wouldn’t have enough actual wood in the bottom rail to mount the mechanism.

Comment: @Mark @ Aloysius Defenestrate  Actually, there are surface mount automatic drop downs that will mount to hollow doors, e.g., https://www.tmhardware.com/Surface-Mounted-Automatic-Door-Bottom/. (not an endorsement).

Comment: @dim I agree that solid core doors usually have higher STC than hollow, but until the gap is blocked, the difference would hardly be measurable, let alone audible.   OP asked only about door seals,  correctly suspecting it to be the primary noise path (and clearly the low-hanging fruit).

Answer (score 12):

There is another type of draft stopper. It is essentially two pieces of foam tube aka pipe insulation. They are sewn into a cloth sleeve. It slides under the door. One piece of foam on either side of the door. It slides across the floor when the door moves.

Comment: Other wise known as a fancy pool noodle, if you want a DIY solution.

Comment: https://a.co/d/1hJXDdW - example, per vendor covers gap up to 1.7".

Answer (score 4):

Take off the door, and screw a strip of wood the same dimensions as the bottom of said door, so it just misses the floor at its smallest gap - maybe >1". Then, the remaining gap can have a draught strip - maybe both sides - to cover a much smaller gap.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly any high-ish density foam preferably brick shaped. It just needs to be sliced to shape and attached with something similar to rubber cement, maybe slightly stronger but not much. And the part that makes this work is a peace of slick flat plastic, like an old screen protector or something similar attached to the foam side touching the floor. that way you have a tight seal, but the slick plastic allows for acceptable pressure equilibrium. it can easily be painted to match the door if desired.

Answer (score -3):

'Sound proofing' is not a thing. The closest you will ever get is a total vacuum, and that's not practical, maybe not even possible.

I suggest, the most common method for reducing sound transmission, an air gap, as used in double-glazing. In your case, that would be a tight-fitting rubber seal either side of the door's bottom edge. PS, I have 40 plus years experience as a sound engineer, but my carpentry skills are a bit rusty (pun not intended).

Comment: I think we can assume the phrase "sound proof" here is shorthand for "improve the STC as much as practical" and we don’t have to address the literal interpretation of "sound proof".